# Php contact form problems

Tags: php

Hey there:) first time using this site.

I'm new to php, DW and I work on a Imac. I have been trying for two days to get a concact form working. I want it to send an email to my gmail, or our company email, when we get it.

I have uploaded it to a FTP server, but when i type in the data I get this:

Server Error
405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.

I really hope you guys can help me out, in some easy understanding terms:P

My HTML:

```
<h2>Kontakt os</h2>

<form class="form" name="contactform" method="post" action="php/send_form_email.php">

<p class="name">
<input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30" placeholder="Fornavn:">
<label for="first_name"></label>
</p>

<div class="seperator1"></div>

<p class="lastname">
<input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30" placeholder="Efternavn:">
<label for="last_name"></label>     
</p>

<div class="seperator1"></div>

<p class="email">
<input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30" placeholder="Email:">
<label for="email"></label>
</p>

<div class="seperator1"></div>

<p class="phone">
<input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30" placeholder="Tlf:">
<label for="telephone"></label>
</p>

<div class="seperator1"></div>

<p class="text">
<textarea name="text" placeholder="Skriv til os her" /></textarea>
<label for="text"></label>
</p>

<p class="submit">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</p>

</form>
```

My PHP code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
$email_to = "mikkelmadsen.info@gmail.com";
$email_subject = "Mysole";


function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "Undskyld, men det ser ud til der er sket en fejl.";
    echo "Fejl står nedeunder.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Gå venligst tilbage for at rette fejlen.<br /><br />";
    die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
    !isset($_POST['text'])) {
    died('Undskyld, men det ser ud til der er sket en fejl.');       
}

$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
$comments = $_POST['text']; // required

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'Forkert email adresse.<br />';
}
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
$error_message .= 'Forkert fornavn.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
$error_message .= 'Forkert efternavn.<br />';
}
if(strlen($text) < 2) {
$error_message .= 'Den tekst du har skrevet er ikke gyldig.<br />';
}
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
}
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
$email_message .= "Text: ".clean_string($text)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->

Klik her <a href="../kontakt.html"></a> at komme tilbage til forsiden.

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: What in the name is `died()` function?

Comment: @Simon_eQ So far as I can read is it an error function

Comment: Rename your HTML page so it has a `.php` file extention

Comment: Why should he rename the html file?

Comment: your server is windows?

Comment: @TobiasKun My guess is that the server is `Windows/IIS` and it's not set up to handle the `POST` verb for `.html` pages..

Comment: I believe the function you meant by `died()` is **`die()`**  - http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.die.php

Comment: So I should rename my concoct.html files to concoct.php? I did that and tryed using DW FTP setup, to test remote. But I get this error:

dynamically-related files could not be resolved because the site definition is not correct

Answer (score 0):

Talk to the webserver host. It's not sure your webserver support posts.

http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html

Comment: I think that was the problem:) thx m8. Called them, and the ftp did not support php or MySQL..... So getting a new one;)

Answer (score 0):

first off all when you develop something use your own PC. use xampp to create yourself a development environment. test it if it works then upload to the server.

this way you earn:
time
you can tract the errors
you change any php settings
you don't need to upload anything to server etc

also for the e-mail you can use your gmail account as a smtp server and send mails from your own pc